# CompletableFuture not getting resolved despite blocking

Tags: java, java-8, future, executorservice, completable-future

I have a usecase wherein , i need to return a completable future based on polling a status from a rest service : 
what i have is :

```
Class Dummy implements Function<DummyObject, CompletionStage<MyMainStatus>> {
    private static final int POLL_INTERVAL = 15;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService service;
    private final StateFullComponent component;

    public Dummy(ScheduledExecutorService service, StateFullComponent component){
       this.service = requireNonNull(service);
       this.component = requireNonNull(component);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<MyMainStatus> apply(DummyObject dummy) {
        CompletableFuture<MyMainStatus> cf1 = new CompletableFuture<>();
        CompletableFuture<MyIntermediateStatus> cf2 = new CompletableFuture<>();

        final ScheduledFuture<?> checkFuture = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
           StatusObject so = someRestServiceCall(dummy);
           if(so.status.ALL_OK){
              cf2.complete(MyIntermediateStatus.OK);
           } else if(so.status.SOME_FAIL){
              Set<RetryJobs> jobs = findRetryJobs(dummy);
              component.add(jobs);
              if(so.status.SOME_FAIL_SOME_PASS) {
             //this block basically monitors the retry jobs
              CompletionStage<MyIntermediateStage> cf3 = 
                       someMethodWhichReturnsStage(component.get(jobs)); 
              cf3.thenCompose(interStatus -> {
                 if(interStatus.equals(MyIntermediateStatus.OK))
                     cf2.complete(MyIntermediateStatus.OK);
                 else
                     cf2.complete(MyIntermediateStatus.FAIL);
                  return cf2;
                }
              }
              , 0, POLL_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.Seconds);

        return cf2.thenCompose((result) -> {
             checkFuture.cancel(true);
             if(result.equals(MyIntermediateStatus.OK))
                  cf1.complete(MyMainStatus.OK);
             else
                  cf1.complete(MyMainStatus.NOT_OK);
             return cf1;
   }
```

Okay, now coming to the problem, what happens is initial polls happen all well and good, and i am also able to schedule retries. Problem arises when the SOME_PASS_SOME_FAIL block comes into play, even when the retry batches have not completed , seems like the future CF2 is completed, since the polling stops and nothing basically happens.
i realize that i am not doing anything with cf3, can that be the cause?
any suggestions to improve the above?
i am doing a .get() on the future i return from the above class

Comment: Even considering that some code is missing, this code does not compile. In example, the `jobs` variable is out of scope when accessed by `component.get(jobs)`. Could you provide a correct snippet of code?

Comment: was looking for inputs more around the usage of futures and if the pattern seems correct or am i missing something

Comment: It would be better if you actually provide a [mcve] because otherwise it might not be possible to understand the problem and help you. Moreover, it seems you are a bit confusing `thenCompose()` and `thenApply`/`thenAccept`. Even though it does not seem to be the cause of the issue, you could replace the first `thenCopmose` by `thenAccept` (without `return`) and the second one by a `thenApply` that simply the main status instead of a stage.